# GNUPlot x-axe as String

Tags: gnuplot

Is ist possible to plot with strings as x-axe?

I have the following file:

> cw15 0,577774
>
> cw255 0,901639
>
> cw1023 0,927813

i tired following:
set datafile separator ","
set yrange [0.0000:1.00000]

```
plot 'meanFrameDropRatio.data' u 2:xticlabel(1) smooth unique ti 'PPS 20 (Tx-Power = 200mW)'
```

but i just get nothing, any ideas? I'm using GNUPlot 4.6

Comment: ok, i found the solution. The problem was that GNUPlot uses Punkt instead of Comma.
I had to add

    set decimalsign locale "de_DE.UTF-8"

to solve the Problem.

Comment: Feel free to post that as a solution and then accept it (when StackOverflow will let you).  That way this question will be "resolved" as far as StackOverflow is concerned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, i found the solution. The problem was that GNUPlot Punkt instead of Komma used.
I had to add

```
set decimalsign locale "de_DE.UTF-8"
```